# Grey Areas in Webapp while using Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-hosting

I have a multi-page web application written in Flutter which uploaded on Firebase hosting . All the pages work fine but half of the homepage is grey. Photo attached. Really appreciate for help.

Also, I'm getting this error when I run: flutter run -d chrome --release

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "ProcessException: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event   
log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

  
Command: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.2b59d482\flutter_tools_chrome_device.4fad7966  --remote-debugging-port=2576 --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check
  --disable-default-apps --disable-translate http://localhost:11541".
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced same issue while host web app in firebase.

the issue is not in firebase host. the issue is in your code. your code will completely work in debug mode. but not in released mode.

1. check every warning in logs.
2. it is mostly happen because of wrong use of **expanded or flexible widget**

Comment: Got you man. So every Error should be  solved before deploying ?

Comment: yes, in my case it was due to expanded widget. it throws the warning like incorrect use of parental data widget.

Comment: you got any waring like incorrect use of parental data widget? in logs

Comment: Actually , I  debugged all the error, but still, the grey areas is available. I also use  firestore in my project . I'm adding firebase sdk to see if the problem is firebase other product

Comment: check your web is working in released mode or not?

Comment: try to run flutter build web --release.

Comment: Hey , Mate ... It's been a hour but still not working . is it possible it's because of app size : it's about 260Mb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234536/discussion-between-dani-m-and-prashant-vaddoriya).